# How can I check which background my button has (between various drawable xml i designed) in my code so that i can modify it?

Tags: java, android, button

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (//button1 background is blue){

            changeBackgroundColorRed();

        }
        else if (//button1 background is red){

            changeBackgroundColorBlue();

        }           
    }

    });
```

The changeBackgroundColor methods are working I just need to know which background they currently have to be able to call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tag of the button depending of what color you have set and get the Tag to check if its currently blue or red.

**In onCreate or similar:**

When instantiating the Button you need to set the tag first to the initial color:

```
button.setTag("blue");
```

**Inside Onclick**

```
if (button.getTag().equals("blue")){ //background is currently blue
    changeBackgroundColorRed();
    button.setTag("red"); //set the Tag to red cause you change the background to red
}
else if (button.getTag().equals("red")){ //background is currently red
    changeBackgroundColorBlue();
    button.setTag("blue"); //set the Tag to blue cause you change the background to blue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the accepted answer is correct it has it doesnot seem to be very elegant(my personal opinion).  Heres my code and it acts as a toggle button. I have set background to android.R.color.black in xm. Changing background requires two steps. First get the current background. Second compare and change it. Something like this should work:

It requires Api level 11.

```
public class Sample extends Activity {
Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(OnClickOKButton());
}

View.OnClickListener OnClickOKButton() {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ColorDrawable currentColor = (ColorDrawable) button1
                    .getBackground();
            int color1 = currentColor.getColor();
            if (color1 == getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)) {
                button1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                        android.R.color.darker_gray));
            } else {
                button1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                        android.R.color.black));
            }
        }
    };
}

}
```